# Push notification don't recieved on some device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am implemented push notification in APP using Google cloud message

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

but I faced problem.

On some devices we receive push on another not. I testing two the same devices on one working on another no. But after "Back up and reset" settings on doesn't working device he start receive Push messages. Does anybody have this problem? Or there are some restrictions on GCM (maybe with accounts on devices or GCM conflict with some program).

Comment: When you say "not working", do you mean the registration failed, or that the messages didn't reach the device? What API level is the device that wasn't working?

Comment: @Eran Messages didn't reach the device. regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID) - id recived from GCM. Both device Samsung S2 (Android 4.0.3). When i send notification before "Back up and reset" they don't recivied, after push message received. APP is the SAME.

Comment: @Eran Now I have 2 APP. On first implemented old GCM where we used for receive ID GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID) - on one device I didn't receive gcm_registration_id. After "Back up and reset" everything work I received messages. On second (same APP implemented http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html method for messages) regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID) - received from GCM but in class GcmBroadcastReceiver onReceive method not fired. After "Back up and reset" everything work I received messages.